# Getting Error while using "this"

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

Getting Error when using "this" in  fragement,instead of that what can i use.Below is the given code:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
private List<DataJobs> datajobs = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private EventsAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
    return rootView;
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new EventsAdapter(datajobs);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(**this**, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    prepareMovieData();
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: DividerItemDecoration (android.content.Context,int) cannot be applied in DividerItemDecoration (tabs.Tab1,int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` instead

```
  recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```